# AddThis Icons Being Blocked on SSL/HTTPS Site

Tags: ssl

I've installed and configured the [AddThis module](https://www.drupal.org/project/addthis) to show sharing buttons to my users. It works great on my local machine. When I put the site on my SSL/HTTPS enabled site however the buttons do not show up (although I see the  they are in in the page inspector) and Chrome gives me JavaScript errors that the script being used to get those icons is calling from http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js...a not-secure link and is being blocked).

Does anyone know how to change the link the addthis module is calling to make it SSL/HTTPS compatible?

Comment: I think this work for you apply patch https://www.drupal.org/files/1403210-https_breaking-1.patch

Comment: I don't have the line it says to remove in the code in my version of the module (7.x-4.0-alpha6). Instead I have a conditional statement for getWidgetUrl that seems to suggest it tests whether or not I'm using 'https' by which I suppose it fails.

Comment: this patch code is already implemented with the function `public function transformToSecureUrl($url)` in alpha version.

Comment: I see, so why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up contacting AddThis and they told me the Drupal module is outdated, and to instead use this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js"></script>
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style 
">
    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
    </div>
```

So I put the first line (the  tag) in my html.tpl.php file and put the rest of the code in a block in my footer. I had to make sure to put all the  tags on the same line otherwise Drupal was forcing 
 tags between them making it impossible to style the toolbox correctly. Making sure the block content was set to 'Full HTML' and I was good to go.

The negative of this approach is that it requires another call to an external script. The positive is it negates the need for another module - you can safely remove 'addthis'.

Answer (score 1):

/admin/config/user-interface/addthis/advanced Service URL's and you can put https instead of http and problem is fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Use secure pages module and make this **Switch back to http pages when there are no matches** option checked on below config page.

sitename/admin/config/system/securepages

Comment: The OP was asking about how to show addthis on https pages. Your answer does not address the issue.